# Trying to make sense of C++ Struct

Tags: c++, struct

In the file f.h there is the following struct:

```
struct Store{
    Store();
    ~Store();
};
```

Inside this struct there is also a line which says `public:`. In the file f.cpp the function Store() is used:

```
Store::Store(){
};
```

Sorry for this all being vague, all I want to know is what the `Store()` and `~Store()` parts do, what the point of the `public:` part is in the struct, and also what the part in f.cpp actually does as I'm having trouble working it out myself (I started learning CPP recently)

Comment: I suggest you keep on learning and ask a question when you have a specific problem.

Comment: You might be interested in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on StackOverflow to help you learn C++.

You won't be successful learning C++ by asking each question on StackOverflow. That's not what StackOverflow is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all I want to know is what the `Store()` and `~Store()` parts do

They are declaring the struct's **constructor** and **destructor**, respectively.

> what the point of the public: part is in the struct

To declare them as publically accessible so outside code can call them.

> and also what the part in f.cpp actually does

Implements the body code of the constructor.  The code in the .h file is just the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The Store() function is called when you create instance of your Store struct and it is called constructor. The ~Store() is the opposite, it is been called when your instance is destroyed, for example, while calling delete.
For this struct you can set functions and those function got access modifiers. Public mean that everyone can access this function (you can call it anywhere in your code).
The Store::Store(){} in the cpp file is the definition of your function, what code will run when you init your class. You can set variables, run other functions and so on.
The header just declare what functions the struct have and the cpp define what those functions does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is recommended you use a class in c++ unless it is a C-style struct:

```
// C++ Class
class Store {
  public:
    Store();
    ~Store();
};

// C-Style Struct
struct Store {
  char *store_name;
}
```

I hope that illustrates the difference between the two, now on to your question:

Store::Store() is the class's constructor used to initialize the data in the class.

Store::~Store() is the class's destructor which is used to free allocated memory, etc.

The keyword public indicates that these items are available to use outside the classs.
By default, all struct members are public.

The keyword protected indicates that these items cannot be used outside the class, but can be inherited.

The keyword private indicates that these items are accessible only from within the class itself.
Members in C++ classes defined using class are private by default.

Comment: Sorry, but I defy your recommendation and use `struct` when I want the default access to be public in C++.  A good C++ book would help the OP.

Comment: Any good C++ book or tutorial would recommend you did not rely on the default access indicator in classes.